# Как сверстать такое поле инпут вместе с кнопкой?

Tags: html, css

[image: инпут с кнопкой]

Как можно сделать вот такую форму?
что не пробовал, постоянно распадается.
Спасибо!

```
<form class="form_group" action="#">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address">
                <button class="btn">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Почему один `html`, где стили то?

Comment: попробуйте кнопке в CSS поставить position: relative и уже использовать Left. right в пикселях, для позиционирования. Например так .btn{position:relative;left:20px;rightL10px;} и вот лефтом и райтом регулировать позиционирование.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно установить абсолютное позиционирование для кнопки и иконки письма (или же прописать иконку в `placeholder`), в то время как для `form` установлены конкретные размеры и `position: relative;`

Либо же используйте отрицательные значения `margin` для позиционирования кнопки.

```css
body, div, form, input, button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #bcbcbc;
}

.form_group {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form_group input {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   padding: 10px 40px;
   border: 2px solid #fff;
   border-radius: 30px;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78434;
}

.form_group span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form_group" action="#">
                <span>&#128231;</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address">
                <button class="btn">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```